# os.times() in Python CGI application

Tags: python

I'm having trouble understanding the documentation of `os.times()`. From http://docs.python.org/library/os.html:

> Return a 5-tuple of floating point numbers indicating accumulated (processor or other) times, in seconds. The items are: user time, system time, children’s user time, children’s system time, and elapsed real time since a fixed point in the past, in that order. See the Unix manual page times(2) or the corresponding Windows Platform API documentation. On Windows, only the first two items are filled, the others are zero.

Finding any other resource on the command seems a bit challenging.

Assuming each CGI call spawns a new python process: what do the first two values of the following result from a `os.times()` actually tell me? What  am I actually measuring if I make use of them?

`(0.2184014, 0.17160109999999998, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They tell you how much processor time (as opposed to time waiting for I/O operations) has been spent in program code (i.e. the python interpreter) and OS kernel code (i.e. processing system calls made by the python interpreter), respectively, by this process so far.

There's some more detail in the [times(2) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/times) referred to by the docs, as well as the [time(7) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/time).

Comment: So. Process time = user time + system time? And does not include I/O operations time?

Comment: Processor time = user time + system time. Does not include I/O operations time, so is usually less than "wallclock" elapsed time, though on a multi-core system it can also be more, since cycles from all CPUs are added together.